# Obter HeaderText de uma coluna numa GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Ao percorrer o evento `RowDataBound` de uma `GridView` pretendo obter o valor do `headertext` da coluna mas não estou conseguindo.

Um exemplo que quero obter:

```
if (e.Row.RowType.ToString().Equals("Header"))
{           
}
else if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
    int tot = e.Row.Cells.Count;
    for (int i = 1; i < tot; i++)
    {
        TextBox txtValor = new TextBox();
        txtValor.Width = 15;
        string produ = e.Row.Header.text //Preciso de obter o valor do titulo da coluna.       
        txtValor.Text = (e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView).Row[produ].ToString();
        e.Row.Cells[i].Controls.Add(txtValor);
    }     
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O seguinte código devolve-lhe o nome da coluna da célula `i` (segundo o seu comentário //Preciso de obter o valor do titulo da coluna):

```
string produ = GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[i].Text;
```

ou então, uma forma alternativa:

```
var cell = GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[i] as DataControlFieldHeaderCell;
if (cell != null)
{
    string headerName = cell.ContainingField.HeaderText;
}
```

(substituía GridView1 pelo nome da sua `GridView`)

Comment: Devolve o vazio, não devolve nenhum valor

Comment: @user6018 vou assumir que está a preencher a gridview através da base de dados, talvez por isso esteja a aparecer como vazio. Editei a resposta com outra solução.